# Какая из хэш-функций от Bob Jenkins используется в Delphi XE8?

Tags: delphi, хеширование, delphi-xe8

Начиная с версии XE8 в составе стандартной библиотеки появился модуль `System.Hash`. Он содержит 3 хэш функции: BobJenkins, MD5, SHA1 (а в поздних версиях в него добавился и SHA2). MD5 и SHA1 достаточно стандартны и известны. Поиск по интернету показал, что Bob Jenkins обозначает несколько разных хэш-алгоритмов (one_at_a_time, lookup2, lookup3, SpookyHash и их вариации?).

Используемый там `THashBobJenkins` отдает хэш длиной 32бита (4 байта).

Хочу узнать точный тип, чтобы по нему уже поискать его стойкость/надежность.

Какая именно хэш-функция от Bob Jenkins используется в Delphi XE8+?

Comment: В XE2 к функции BobJenkinsHash есть комментарий-ссылка http://burtleburtle.net/bob/c/lookup3.c . В более поздних версиях ссылка убрана, но единственное отличие - на старте используется `Cardinal(Len shl 2)`, а в XE2 - `Cardinal(Len)`. На основании этого смею утверждать, что используется lookup3